# Leg position different in Blender and Unity

Tags: animation, rigging, unity

I created a rifle aiming action for my character where the body is turned 45 degrees to the right and the arms are put straight forward, just like you would aim in real life. But when I try to use this action as an animation in Unity the legs are not positioned at an angle, it looks like they're forced to be on the x-axis. I'm using Mecanim. Is there a way to fix this?
Also, I don't know if this is the right place to post this, since it's kinda a Unity problem.
If not, then I apologize.

[image: Blender]
[image: Unity]

Comment: can you send the blender file?

Comment: [is this correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2zHv.png)

Comment: Yup!
In the meantime I actually achieved the same result by leaving the root bone alone and rotating everything else instead.
Is that also what you did?

Comment: I actually did nothing it worked for me in unity 2019.4.7f1. it seems it's kind of bug